# Hover on Skybox in Unity for Gear VR

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I am new to unity and but want to create a Gear VR experience where you have a scene with a panorama skybox, and can view videos after hovering over a building that is on the skybox.

I was hoping to ask two questions:

1. What are common VR object hover interactions are like?
2. Do I need to superimpose a plane or some other object over the areas on the skybox or is there a better way to do this?

Any help in this area would be awesome!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Interactions are similar to traditional experiences (as in shoot a ray and see if there is a hit)
2. That depends on what you want to achieve, but in all likelihood: yes. You will need to add colliders and overlays to create an interactive experience.

Here is a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766211/hover-menu-on-skybox-in-unity/44769674#44769674) I posted recently on that subject. Unity also provides a good starting kit called [VR Samples](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/51519), it's free and should help you get going.

hth.